# How to repetitively insert an expression (whose length >= 2) in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

e.g. I would like to insert "foo " 10 times.

I can only think of three ways: repeat last command using C-x z, repetitively insert from register, or a macro.

For the first two, I tried prefix argument C-u 10, but not working. For the macro, its key-stroke count is a bit too much.

The most intuitive way, C-u C-y, is not working either.

What is the most handy way of doing this?

Comment: How abut using the macro `dotimes`?:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/dotimes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like doing this as well, and so wrote this function:

```
(defun my-yank ()
  "Like yank, but with prefix number yank that many times."
  (interactive "*")
  (when (and delete-selection-mode (region-active-p))
    (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end)))
  (if (and current-prefix-arg (integerp current-prefix-arg))
      (dotimes (x current-prefix-arg)
        (yank))
    (yank)))
```

Answer (score 3):

> For the macro, its key-stroke count is a bit too much.

Really? If you're yanking the last kill 10 times, then it's:

<kbd>F3</kbd><kbd>C-y</kbd><kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>

or <kbd>F3</kbd><kbd>C-y</kbd><kbd>M-1</kbd><kbd>M-0</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>

Either way, it's only two keys on top of specifying the prefix arg and performing the yank.

Comment: great tip. thanks. I usually do <kbd> C-x ( </kbd> [Macro] <kbd> C-x ) </kbd> because I am a bit lazy moving left-hand up to reach function keys.

Comment: Supplying a repeat count to `F4` / `C-x )` as an argument to execute the macro `n` times right away? Awesome! :) For whatever reason, I never picked that up when reading the manual on [Keyboard Macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html) ...